# How to subset a dataframe with multiple conditions involving days and values for two factor variables

Tags: r

I have a dataset with the structure shown below.

```
dat <- data.frame(
   event = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), 
   place =c("p1", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p4","p4","p4", "p5"), 
   day = c("May 1","May 2","May 3", "May 4", "May 5", "May 6", "May 7", "May 8", 
           "May 9", "May 1"),     
   visits = c(2,1,4,1,2,4,8,2,3,1))
```

I would like to identify, for each event, the place that have the highest value of visits for 2 (or at least 2) different days.

Result I want:

```
event place visits
A     p1     3
B     p3     7
C     p4     5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do this would be to first add count for each group, select group with more than 1 count and select the `event` with maximum `visits`.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  add_count(event, place) %>%
  filter(n > 1) %>%
  group_by(event, place) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(visits)) %>%
  slice(which.max(n))

#  event place     n
#  <fct> <fct> <dbl>
#1 A     p1        3
#2 B     p3        7
#3 C     p4        5
```

Comment: This answer was also useful. Thanks, Ronak!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, this does what you're after:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  group_by(event, place) %>% 
  summarise(different_days = n_distinct(day), 
            visits = sum(visits)) %>% 
  filter(different_days >= 2) %>%
  select(-different_days) # Only to match desired result exactly
```

Produces

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   event [3]
  event place visits
  <fct> <fct>  <dbl>
1 A     p1         3
2 B     p3         7
3 C     p4         5
```

Comment: Very useful answer! Thanks MSR for your quick reply ! Have a good one

Answer (score 0):

You could `aggregate()` over `"event"` and `"place"` and apply `length()` and `sum()` as `FUN` argument.

```
(a <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, 
             aggregate(visits ~ event + place, dat, FUN=function(a) c(length(a), sum(a)))))

#   event place visits.1 visits.2
# 1     A    p1        2        3
# 2     A    p2        1        4
# 3     B    p3        3        7
# 4     B    p4        1        8
# 5     C    p4        2        5
# 6     C    p5        1        1
```

The subset gives you what you want:

```
a[a[3] > 1, -3]
#   event place visits.2
# 1     A    p1        3
# 3     B    p3        7
# 5     C    p4        5
```

Comment: I like the way you solved this question with the columns for the number of visits! Thank you, jay.sf!